# Doubt on a certain definition of adjoint pairs

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:\mathbf C\to\mathbf D$ and $G:\mathbf D\to\mathbf C$ be two functors such that, for $D\in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf D)$, the functor $\mathbf D(F-,D)$ is represented by $\mathbf C(-,GD)$. *Is it true that $F\dashv G$?*

I tried to prove that the representing isomorphisms "glue" to an isomorphism $\mathbf D(F-,-)\cong \mathbf C(-,G-)$ natural in the two variables; the naturality in $D$  comes from the naturality of $\eta:1_\mathbf C\to GF$. Here the components of the unit are the universal elements of the representing isomorphisms, by definition; however I can't see if in this situation such components are automatically natural, or if it is not granted; I feel like the problem may be with the counit, but I can't focus it. Thanks for any clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hypothesis only implies that $F$ has a right adjoint whose object map agrees with $G$.
It can happen that $G$ is not the right adjoint of $F$.

For example, suppose $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are both the one-object groupoid with three morphisms ($\textrm{id}, a, a^{-1}$).
Let $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be the identity functor and let $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ be the functor that swaps $a$ and $a^{-1}$.
Then $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ certainly has a right adjoint, and there are bijections $\mathcal{D} (F C, D) \cong \mathcal{C} (C, G D)$ natural in *either* $C$ *or* $D$, but there is no bijection that is natural in both $C$ and $D$ simultaneously.
The reason is that functors $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ are isomorphic if and only if they are equal, but $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ is (by construction) not equal to the right adjoint of $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$.